# cannot run flutter app on iOS simulator. Have already tried a lot of things

Tags: xcode, flutter

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (2nd generation) in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           13.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    <module-includes>:1:1: error: umbrella header for module 'GoogleDataTransport' does not include header 'GDTCORDataFuture.h' [-Werror,-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    #import "Headers/GoogleDataTransport-umbrella.h"
    ^
    <module-includes>:1:1: error: umbrella header for module 'GoogleDataTransport' does not include header 'GDTCORStoredEvent.h' [-Werror,-Wincomplete-umbrella]
    2 errors generated.
    In file included from /Users/leozhang/Desktop/DesktopStuff/aSenior Design/BW_MOBILE_APP/AR-Tools-BW/boston_whaler_app/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GDTCCTLibrary/GDTCOREvent+NetworkConnectionInfo.m:17:
    /Users/leozhang/Desktop/DesktopStuff/aSenior Design/BW_MOBILE_APP/AR-Tools-BW/boston_whaler_app/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GDTCCTLibrary/Private/GDTCOREvent+NetworkConnectionInfo.h:17:9: fatal error: could not build module 'GoogleDataTransport'
    #import <GoogleDataTransport/GDTCOREvent.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    3 errors generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (2nd generation).
```

I've looked at solutions online for hours already and nothing has worked. From cocoapods to googleservices-info.plist file changes on Xcode, but no luck :( Please help me :'(

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3934

Comment: No :( I tried... thanks for trying tho

Comment: Did you find the solution. Help!

Comment: not for this one but my iOS simulator works...for now

Answer (score 1):

`flutter clean` solved this for me.